# How to use between calculation in SQL subquery?

Tags: sql

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT Hours FROM Time WHERE Time.Pay_Date = s.Pay_Date) as Hours
FROM Students s
WHERE s.Pay_Date BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-02-01'
```

Currently my sql query is like this I want my subquery (Hours) to read:

```
SELECT Hours FROM Time WHERE Time.Pay_Date BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-02-01'
```

But s.Pay_Date doesnt give me BETWEEN 2015-01-01' AND '2015-02-01'.  Is there a way around this?  I know can simply just put the date numbers in but that wouldn't be ideal with the query I am dealing with.

Thanks

Comment: "But s.Pay_Date doesnt work like that." What does that mean?

Comment: Hi dan08

When I do the query, s.Pay_Date only equals to '2015-01-01' and doesn't use the between function

Comment: Can you put some exemple of data stored in tables and expected result?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: A sub-query in Select must return a scalar value, here in your query it may return mora than one value.

Comment: Are you sure in your syntax? Shouldn't it be `BETWEEN date1 AND date2`?

Comment: sorry i corrected the syntax

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Pervasive PSQL.  It uses SQL

Comment: Your problem looks like a `JOIN` issue, but I just wanted to mention that I never recommend using `BETWEEN`. How often do you see a question where someone has problems with `s.Pay_Date >='2015-01-01' AND s.Pay_Date<'2015-02-01'`?  you don't because it is very clear `>=` and `<` are easily understood.

Answer (score 1):

in this scenario you need a simple `join` also correct the `between` statement.

```
SELECT t.Hours
FROM Time t join Students s on t.Pay_Date = s.Pay_Date
WHERE s.Pay_Date BETWEEN '2015-01-01' and '2015-02-01'
```

Comment: Hi Farhang,

Thanks but can this be done within a subquery?  I have to use a subquery for various reasons

Daniel

Comment: Hi, you are welcome, yes of course you can use subqueries also but if you see the cost and execution plan I think direct join is better.